# Create XSD for XML with multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, xml-namespaces

I will receive XML documents that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EFOCE>
        <CustomerLegalEntity>
            <FullName>Bob Smith</FullName>
        </CustomerLegalEntity>
        <Extension xmlns:d3p1="CactusExtension">
            <CustomerPersonNo>100555</CustomerPersonNo>
            <DeliveryExtensions>
                <DeliveryExtension i:type="d3p1:DeliveryExtension">
                    <ContractCode>123456</ContractCode>
                </DeliveryExtension>
            </DeliveryExtensions>
        </Extension>
    </EFOCE>
</root>
```

I cannot change the XML documents in any way. I now have to write a schema file (or a number of schema files) that will validate these XML documents. In BizTalk I have tried the function "Add Generated Items" which will give me this single XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:d3p1="CactusExtension"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="EFOCE">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="CustomerLegalEntity">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Extension">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="CustomerPersonNo" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                    <xs:element name="DeliveryExtensions">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="DeliveryExtension">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ContractCode" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But this XSD file is not correct, because it will not validate the XML. It gives me this error message in BizTalk when I try to validate the XML file against the generated XSD:

`error BEC2004: This is an invalid xsi:type 'CactusExtension:DeliveryExtension'.`

It also gives me this warning, but I assume it is not the main problem:

`warning BEC1007: Node "<Schema>" - Target namespace is empty.`

I guess the problem is that elements EFOCE and ContractCode are belonging to the empty namespace "", but the element DeliveryExtension belongs to the namespace CactusExtension. I have tried to define DeliveryExtension within its own XSD file and then include that from the main XSD. This goes well for that element, but then other errors occur for the child element ContractCode which is not in the namespace CactusExtension.

How can I write the XSD file(s) ?

**Added based on Michael Kay's answer:**

I have now modified the main schema file like this (introducing an `xs:import` and changing the element DeliveryExtension):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:d3p1="CactusExtension"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="CactusExtension" schemaLocation="DeliveryExtension.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="EFOCE">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="CustomerLegalEntity">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Extension">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="CustomerPersonNo" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                    <xs:element name="DeliveryExtensions">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="DeliveryExtension" type="d3p1:DeliveryExtension"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And I have added a separate schema file DeliveryExtension.xsd with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="CactusExtension"
xmlns="CactusExtension"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="DeliveryExtension">
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="ContractCode" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I now get the following error message (along with the same warning as before) when I try to validate the XML file against the XSD:

`error BEC2004: The element 'DeliveryExtension' has invalid child element 'ContractCode'. List of possible elements expected: 'ContractCode' in namespace 'CactusExtension'.`

I think this error occurs because in the XML file, ContractCode does not belong to the namespace CactusExtension.

Is there a way to get the element ContractCode validated?

Comment: Basically your namespace prefix d3p1 isn't defined in your root of your XML, so your XML isn't even valid.  And that warning is also a clue, that you are missing a namespace.  So at the moment rather than having "multiple namespaces" you have none apart from the standard XMLSchema namespace.

Comment: P.S. If you did put in a default namespace in plus defined the namespace prefix d3p1 with another namespace, you will find that when you do generate items, you will have multiple XSD files with the root one referencing the other via an Import, as you can only have one namespace per XSD.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf You've invented a rule that doesn't exist. Neither wellformedness nor validity requires namespaces to be declared on the root element.

Comment: @MichaelKay It will be needed if you want it to play nice in BizTalk, which is what this question is about

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I've no idea what's needed to play nicely with Biztalk, but your suggestion that the XML isn't valid is quite incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema is correct, but not complete. Your instance document contains a reference to the schema type `Q{CactusExtension}DeliveryExtension`, but there is no way that the schema generator can know where to find this type.

My guess (but it's only a guess, and there's no way the schema generator could make such a guess) is that you want to define a complex type

```
<xs:complexType name="DeliveryType">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="ContractCode" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

with target namespace = `CactusExtension`. Because this is a different namespace from the main schema document, it needs to go in a separate schema document linked via `xs:import`.

No schema generator is ever going to give you an output that captures all the semantics of your data model. It's only ever a starting point to save you some of the grunt-work.

**=== LATER ===**

You've implemented this suggestion and added it to your question. But you got an error because the declaration of element ContractCode is now in the CactusExtension namespace. You need to declare the element as `<xs:element ref="ContractCode"/>`, with the element declaration being moved to be a global declaration in the no-namespace schema document; you'll also need to add an xs:import to make this reference valid.

**=== LATER ===**

I don't like to provide full code for people, I prefer to give advice and encouragement, but since you're struggling, here are the two schema documents:

root.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="CactusExtension" schemaLocation="DeliveryExtension.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="EFOCE">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="CustomerLegalEntity">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="FullName" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Extension">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="CustomerPersonNo" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                                        <xs:element name="DeliveryExtensions">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                  <xs:element name="DeliveryExtension"
                                                      type="cactus:DeliveryExtension" xmlns:cactus="CactusExtension"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ContractCode" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
</xs:schema>
```

DeliveryExtension.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="CactusExtension"
   elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:import schemaLocation="root.xsd"/>
   <xs:complexType name="DeliveryExtension">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="ContractCode"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Your instance document is valid against this schema (tested with the Saxon schema processor running under Oxygen).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I could not make it work. I have updated my question with a section based on your suggestions. Did I misunderstand some of your advice, or will I just have to add a little tweek somewhere to make it work?